# Custom ASP.NET SqlMemberShip Provider for RavenDB

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ravendb, sqlmembershipprovider

How to Customize ASP.NET SqlMemberShip Provider using RavenDB and MVC4.From where i can start??I have searced a lot about this.Please provide me with good turorials links.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can not customize `SqlMembershipProvider`, but you can create your own `Membership` that works with `RavenDb`.

There's a good example created by Martijn Boland, check http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2010/11/25/raven-db-asp-net-membership-provider/

You can download the `Membership` source code, it works with an embedded database, I think you can change that if needed, and it has a sample web aplication. Here is the link for the download page

https://github.com/martijnboland/RavenDBMembership